# How to take from user the right value for multiple choices?

Tags: c#

I want the programm to go further when the user puts the correct value (1,2,3...)

```
            Console.WriteLine("Choose money to bet: 1€, 2€, 3€, 4€, 5€, 10€, 15€, " +
                "20€, 30€, 50€, 100€");

            //int y = 0;
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int y) || y != 1 || y != 2)
                    //|| y != 3 || y  != 4 || y != 5 || y != 10 || y != 15 || y != 20
                    //|| y != 30 || y != 50 || y != 100 || y <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose correct money to bet: 1€, 2€, 3€, 4€, 5€, " +
                    "10€, 15€, 20€, 30€, 50€, 100€");
            }
```

Comment: It´s pretty unclear to me what your problem is. What do you mean by "go further"? Doesn´t the code do what you want? What is your user-input and what is the expected outcome?

Comment: consider using a collection such as a `HashSet`

Comment: The condition should be `!int.TryParse(...) || y != 1 && y != 2 && ... && y != 100` or something equivalent. Right now you have an infinite loop. But really consider using `HashSet` or a `switch` statement for this

Answer (score 1):

Use Hashset for this, you will have and call Contains(y) to check if it correct, like this :

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
HashSet<int> allowedNumbers = new HashSet<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50, 100 });
string allowedNumbersString = string.Join(", ", allowedNumbers.Select(n => n + "€"));

Console.WriteLine("Choose money to bet: " + allowedNumbersString);
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int y) || !allowedNumbers.Contains(y))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Choose correct money to bet: " + allowedNumbersString);
}
```